# Connection error with PHPMailer and SMTP: node name or service name not known

Tags: php, email, smtp, phpmailer, smtp-auth

I'm using PHPMailer to generate mails in PHP (PHP Version 5.3.7). But I have tried it again and again, but PHPMailer doesn't work with the settings from my provider but with my gmail account.
My settings:

```
SMTP = true
SMTPAuth = true
CharSet = UTF-8
SethSecure = ""
Host = smtp.strato.de
User = myemail
Password = **********
port = 587
```

But PHPMailer returns the following messages (in debug mode):

```
SMTP -> ERROR: Failed to connect to server: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed:
node name or service name not known (0)
The following From address failed: info@burk-co.com : Called Mail() without being connected
```

Please help me due to I don't know what has caused this error and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like your DNS server is not resolving smtp.strato.de.  Try opening a command prompt on your server, and typing:

```
nslookup smtp.strato.de
```

Does it resolve?  If not, try using a different DNS server (by change /etc/resolve.conf).  It does in fact resolve on a server that I tested from.

Comment: I have no access to server console but, as I have written below, I have fixed the problem. Thank you for your help, if the error occurs again I will test your solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have the problem on my own, it seems that I have forgotten to add the FROM email adresse in PHPMailer.