# Why can't PHPMailer connect to gmail server

Tags: php, email, smtp, phpmailer

I am trying to use PHPMailer to send an email.  I am using the latest version (5.2.8) installed using Git.  My PHP version is 5.5.11 and is running on Centos 6.4 with Apache 2.2.  I am running the script provided under `examples/gmail.php` (also available at http://phpmailer.worxware.com/index.php?pg=examplebgmail) except that I changed my username and password to my actual gmail credentials.  My gmail credentials work with PHPMailer 5.0.0.

When running the script, I get the following error:

```
SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known (0)
SMTP connect() failed.
Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed.
```

If I run the script in my  PhpED IDE, I get exception `SMTP connection() failed` from line 1195 in class.phpmailer.php (line 1195 is shown below).

```
if (!$this->smtpConnect()) {
   throw new phpmailerException($this->lang('smtp_connect_failed'), self::STOP_CRITICAL);
}
```

Per earlier answer [Connection error with PHPMailer and SMTP: node name or service name not known](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17839056/connection-error-with-phpmailer-and-smtp-node-name-or-service-name-not-known), I tried the following with the following results:

```
[root@devserver ~]# nslookup smtp.gmail.com
Server:         192.168.0.1
Address:        192.168.0.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
smtp.gmail.com  canonical name = gmail-smtp-msa.l.google.com.
Name:   gmail-smtp-msa.l.google.com
Address: 173.194.79.108
Name:   gmail-smtp-msa.l.google.com
Address: 173.194.79.109

[root@devserver ~]#

[Michael@devserver ~]$ ping smtp.gmail.com
PING gmail-smtp-msa.l.google.com (74.125.25.108) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from pa-in-f108.1e100.net (74.125.25.108): icmp_seq=1 ttl=47 time=18.6 ms
```

What is causing this error and how do I fix it?  Thank you

Comment: Interesting.  The error message that you are getting from phpmailer is indicating a DNS problem, but nslookup is resolving the name correctly.  Out of curiosity, if you do `ping smtp.gmail.com` from the command line, does it resolve correctly, and does smtp.gmail.com respond?

Comment: It's a little surprising that ping (which uses getaddrinfo, like phpmailer uses) is returning a different IP than nslookup.  But, they are both google IP addresses, so it could just be some round-robin DNS scheme that smtp.gmail.com is using.  You're following the example at  http://phpmailer.worxware.com/index.php?pg=examplebgmail, so you are trying to configure phpmailer to connect to smtp.gmail.com on port 587, correct?  If so, from the command line, can you try, `telnet smtp.gmail.com 587`?  Does it connect successfully?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42471693/phpmailer-using-gmail-gives-error/42472146?noredirect=1#comment72085437_42472146